# FXML CustomMenuItem Example

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm having a hard time finding an example of a CustomMenuItem in FXML. Based on the API docs, I was trying this:

```
<SplitMenuButton fx:id="dwnldBtn" text="Download"
    maxWidth="10000" maxHeight="10000" prefHeight="10000"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" onAction="#handleDownloadBtn">
    <items>
        <CustomMenuItem  >
            <button text="Download All" onAction="#handleDownloadAllBtn"/>
        </CustomMenuItem>
    </items>
</SplitMenuButton>
```

But it seems this is syntactically wrong. I want to use a button within a CustomMenuItem, because (unlike a regular MenuItem) a button can be resized (MenuItem lacks properties like maxWidth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html). `CustomMenuItem` has a property called [`content`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#contentProperty) that determines the node displayed in the menu item.

```xml
<CustomMenuItem>
    <content>
        <Button text="..." onAction="#..."/>
    </content>
</CustomMenuItem>
```